# Is Global Entry active immediately after the interview?

Tags: usa, global-entry

My GE application has been approved and I'm thinking of scheduling my interview a couple of days before a domestic trip in hopes I can participate in Pre-Check.

Does anyone know if they will give me my KTN (Known Traveler Number) immediately at the conclusion of the interview or will I have to wait to receive the card by mail?

Someone said the agent "placed a special sticker on the last page of my passport."  Does anyone know if showing that sticker is sufficient to allow the use domestic Pre-Check?

Comment: Do you mind giving some context? What is Global Entry? a service providing visas? to which country(ies)?

Comment: Global Entry is a trusted traveler program for the USA, pre-approving folks for expedited entry through US Customs and Immigration.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2019-09-30, right at the end of the interview, the CBP interviewer will give you a flyer that mentions that the global entry is immediately activated:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Your GE application has only been pre-screened, you are not approved for the Global Entry Program until after the interview has taken place.  Normally you get your card by mail and then have to activate the card before everything is 100% ready.

I didn't ask if I could get the number earlier, simply went through the interview process.  You might try calling and asking if you can get your number at the conclusion of the interview.

Answer (score 4):

As Tom points out, your Global Entry application is only completed after the interview. The Conditional Approval notice is only enough to schedule an interview, not to use GE.

At the end of the interview, the CBP officer will tell you if your application was successful or not. If it wasn't, they may say they need to check further things (I've read about one person on FlyerTalk who had to wait another week).

Assuming that you passed the interview, and they welcome you to the program, then about an hour after the interview you can log into the [GOES website](https://goes-app.cbp.dhs.gov/) and view your Global Entry Membership Number. That number can then immediately be used as your Known Traveller number for TSA Pre. Later that day, you'll also get an email from

An hour or so after the interview, you should be able to get your number from the GOES website. Later that day you should get an email from CBP with a subject like "GOES - Account Status Change". That won't have your membership number in, but is a sign that when you log into GOES you'll be able to download the formal membership approval letter which does have it. (Or you can just see the number once you're logged in!)

If you're a US permanent resident, they'll also post you a GE card, which may take a few weeks to arrive. However, your membership is active once your successful interview is over, and you can use GE terminals + TSA Pre from then on even while waiting for the physical card. (Non US residents don't get the card)